# JavaScript function does not run when called from Flash

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, actionscript-3

I have a .php page, which has a JavaScript function in it, and runs that function, if something is correct in MySQL database. I know the function works.

So my php file looks like this:

**thephp.php**:

```
<?php
$should_i_run_the_function = checkDatabase();
if(!$should_i_run_the_function){die("you can't");}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script> 
<script>
function myFunction()
{
/* works in browser */
make_an_AJAX_call_and_insert_something_to_database();
}
    <?php
    if($should_i_run_the_function)
    {
    ?>
    myFunction();
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This works as it should, when I open the page in browser.

But when I call it from **ActionScript 3**, like this:

```
public function CallURL()
{
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/thephp.php'); 
    var variables:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
    variables.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT; 
    variables.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Ajax_completeHandler()); 
    try 
    { 
        variables.load(request); 
    }  
    catch (error:Error) 
    { 
        trace("Unable to load URL: " + error); 
    } 
}
```

the completeHandler function shows the content of thephp.php correctly, and it does not `die("you can't")` but it doesn't do the mysql insert in JavaScript.

I tried to simplify the code as much as I can, so what could be the problem?

Does JavaScript require the "client" to be a browser to run?

I also tried `ExternalInterface` but it does not work for that function, and I would like to know if I can run the JS code by a `URLRequest`.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You pointed out the thing :

```
Does JavaScript require the "client" to be a browser to run?
```

Yes, of course, the javascript is executed by the browser, not by the HTTP request.